# Subsetting row numbers of data frames stored in list having same values of integers stored in list

Tags: r

I am not so familiar yet in handling data frames stored in list.

I have a list of integers which are representing basically the index of the rows of two data frames (df_nameA, df_nameB) :

```
str(list1)
List of 2
$ df_nameA  :int [1:3] 3 4 6
$ df_nameB  :int [1:3] 1 2 4

df_nameA
nrow  col1.  col 3
 1.    a.    A1
 2.    b.    A2
 3     c     B1
 4.    d     B2
 5.    e     C1
 6.    f     C2
df_nameB
nrow  col1.  col 3
 1.    g     D1
 2.    h     D2
 3     i     E1
 4.    l     E2
 5.    m     F1
 6.    n     F2
list2<-list(df_nameA, df_nameB)
str(list2)
List of 2  :  6 observation and 3 variables
  $:'dataframe'....
```

Desired output:

```
df_nameA
nrow  col1.  col 3 
 3     c     B1
 4.    d     B2
 6.    f     C2
df_nameB
nrow  col1.  col 3
 1.    g     D1
 2.    h     D2
 4.    l     E2
```

Basically I would like to subset the data frames in list2 based on the values stored in list 1.

I wrote something like this but it does not seem to work:

```
for(i in seq_along(list1)){
  for(i in seq_along(list2)){
    lapply(list2, function(x) {return(x[x$nrow %in% list1[[i]],])})
  }}
```

The code seems to be subsetting the rows 1,2,4 from both data frames
Any advice on my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` in the following way or the `for` loop as below

**lapply**

```
names(list2) <- c("df_nameA", "df_nameB")
lapply(names(list2), function(x) list2[[x]][list2[[x]]$nrow %in% list1[[x]], ])

# [[1]]
#   nrow col1. col.3
# 3    3     c    B1
# 4    4     d    B2
# 6    6     f    C2
# 
# [[2]]
#   nrow col1. col.3
# 1    1     g    D1
# 2    2     h    D2
# 4    4     l    E2
```

**for-loop**

```
names(list2) <- c("df_nameA", "df_nameB")
for (x in names(list2)) {
  list2[[x]] <- list2[[x]][list2[[x]]$nrow %in% list1[[x]], ]
}

list2

# $`df_nameA`
#   nrow col1. col.3
# 3    3     c    B1
# 4    4     d    B2
# 6    6     f    C2
# 
# $df_nameB
#   nrow col1. col.3
# 1    1     g    D1
# 2    2     h    D2
# 4    4     l    E2
```

**Data**
The data in reproducible format:

```
list1 <- list(df_nameA = c(3, 4, 6), 
              df_nameB = c(1, 2, 4))

list2 <- list(data.frame(nrow = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                         col1. = c("a.", "b.", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
                         col.3 = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2")), 
              data.frame(nrow = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                         col1. = c("g", "h", "i", "l", "m", "n"), 
                         col.3 = c("D1", "D2", "E1", "E2", "F1", "F2")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `i` in your second loop:
This might work:

```
for(i in seq_along(list1)){
  list2[[i]][ list2[[i]]$nrow %in% list1[[i]],]
}
```

Comment: Now with your code is taking the df_nameB and subsetting it correctly but I am not getting the subset of the other df, sorry, I am not so familiar about that...also, when I type list2 [[i]] it returns the last element of the list which is strange

Comment: Hi sorry, your code is correct, actually I need to create an empty list and save each newly created element in the empty list otherwise it is overwriting it

Comment: for(i in seq_along(list1)){
  newest[[i]]<-list2[[i]][ list2[[i]]$nrow %in% list1[[i]],]
}